# allowfullscreen not working for YouTube Embeds on Chrome

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, youtube

allowfullscreen not working for YouTube Embeds on Chrome.

Reference link - https://www.searchunify.com/video/fuel-a-seamless-transition-from-case-first-to-knowledge-first-model-of-support-with-cognitive-technology/

Comment: the person embedding a video has some settings for the videos. One of those is to not allow full-screen viewing. Contact the administrator of the page you have watched the embedded video and ask them to enable full-screen

Comment: @Moishy thank you for your response, we notice the same video and the same code is working on a test domain. 

ex - https://docs-dev.suva.ai/Content/test-video.htm is working and https://www.searchunify.com/video/elevate-self-service-and-support-success-with-searchunifys-ai-powered-analytics/ is not working